# Spec files are being linted after I included exclude in angular-cli.json

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, tslint, codelyzer

I have an angular 4 app and manually created 2 .spec files for a class. When I run `nglint`, it will lint the 2 spec files. The spec files that were included when I generated a component with the angular-cli are not being linted however (which is what I want)

I have added the following property to my .angular-cli.json file, but it still lints the files:

```
"lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/**/*.spec.ts"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/**/*.spec.ts"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/**/*.spec.ts"
    }
],
```

My spec files are located within /src/app/folder/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried now, once you add `"**/**/*.spec.ts"` to `angular-cli.json - lint - exclude`, it will stop linting any `.spec` file down from the `app` folder, no mater how deep you nest the folders.

This is the `angular-cli.json` code I tested with:

```
"lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "**/**/*.spec.ts"]
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: The selector of the directive "ClickOutsideDirective" should be used as attribute . How to avoid this issue....:) please help me out.... Thanks in advance